# saltstack trying to update php.ini file

Tags: salt-stack

I am quite new to salt, but I am trying to update our PHP.ini file. Specifically I want to populate the timezone field:

```ini
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =
```

Following the saltstack docs, I am using SALT.STATES.INI_MANAGE

This was my latest attempt:

```yaml
# set timezone in php.ini
/etc/php.ini:
  ini.options_present:
    - separator: '='
    - sections:
      Date:
        "date.timezone": 'America/Chicago'
```

But receive the following error:

```
    ERROR executing 'state.apply': 'Date' is an invalid keyword argument for 'ini.options_present'
```

I have tried several other iterations, but I keep getting errors on this very simple issue

Comment: Could be an indentation issue. `Date:` should be indented to 1 level more than `sections:`

Answer (score 0):

It's an indentation issue. Following the documentation example, it should be:

```yaml
/etc/php.ini:
  ini.options_present:
    - sections:
        Date:
          date.timezone: America/Chicago
```